# How can I grab the key of a list item generated from a map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am learning React, and I've tried searching for solutions to my problem both on stackoverflow and on React's own documentation, but I am still stumped.

Essentially, I have a list of 10 subreddits that is being mapped to list items in the form of the `subredditsArray` variable.

I render the results, and try to pass the selected item when I click that list item to my `getSubredditInfo` function. However, this doesn't work - `event.target.key` is undefined. (To clarify, I am looking to grab the key of the single list element that I have clicked).

When I try to just get `event.target`, I get the actual htmlElement (ex: `<li>Dota2</li>`), where as I want to get the key, or at least this value into a string somehow without the tags. I also tried putting my onClick method in the list tag of the map function, but that did not work.

Here is the relevant code:

```
//this is where I get my data
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://www.reddit.com/api/search_reddit_names.json?query=dota2')
    .then(results => {
        return results.json();
    })
    .then(redditNames => {
        //this is there I set my subreddits state variable to the array of strings
        this.setState({subreddits: redditNames.names});
    })
}

   getSubredditInfo(event){
    //console.log(event.target.key); <-- DOESNT WORK

}

render() {

 var subredditsArray = this.state.subreddits.map(function(subreddit){
    return (<li key={subreddit.toString()}>{subreddit}</li>);
});

  return (
    <div className="redditResults">
      <h1>Top 10 subreddits for that topic</h1>
      <ul onClick={this.getSubredditInfo}>{subredditsArray}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My questions essentially boil down to:

1. How do I grab the key value from my list object?
2. Additionally, is there a better way to generate the list than I currently am?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Added my componentDidMount function in hopes it clarifies things a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {subreddits:[]};
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://www.reddit.com/api/search_reddit_names.json?query=dota2')
    .then(results => {
        return results.json();
    })
    .then(redditNames => {
        //this is there I set my subreddits state variable to the array of strings
        this.setState({subreddits: redditNames.names});
    })
  }
  
  getSubredditInfo(subreddit){
     console.log(subreddit);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div className="redditResults">
      <h1>Top 10 subreddits for that topic</h1>
      <ul>
        { 
            this.state.subreddits.map((subreddit)=>{
                return (<li key={subreddit.toString()} onClick={()=>this.getSubredditInfo(subreddit)}>{subreddit}</li>);
            })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

please check the `onClick` event handler now. its an arrow function and its calling the `getSubredditInfo` function with your `subreddit` now. so you will get it there.

so its basically different way of calling the handler to pass data to the handler.

it works as you expect it to.

Comment: So I tried something similar earlier in my efforts, and it didn't work. I get an undefined error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSubredditInfo' of undefined"

Comment: can you tell me about the content of your subreddits array? is it string array? or object array? i am trying to create a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: It's an array of strings.

Comment: Your were getting error:  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSubredditInfo' of undefined" only because you were using conventional function. notice i use arrow function and this does not block the `this`. so its working now.

Comment: @ddantas you can run my code snippet now and it works perfectly as you expect it to.

Comment: I see! It ended up working! Can you explain why the lambda works versus this.getSubredditsInfo?

Comment: the lambda/arrow function does not block `this` but normal anonymous function blocks `this` and that is why you were getting `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this? I'm not sure what you want to do.

```
getSubredditInfo(e, subreddit) {
  console.log(subreddit)
}

render() {
  const { subreddits } = this.state
  var subredditsArray = subreddits.map(subreddit => (
    <li 
      key={subreddit.toString()} 
      onClick={(e) => {
        this.getSubredditInfo(e, subreddit)
      }}
    >
      {subreddit}
    </li>
  ))

  return (
    <div className="redditResults">
      <h1>Top 10 subreddits for that topic</h1>
      <ul>{subredditsArray}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The key purpose is to pass your subreddit to the onClick function so you will receive the value while you click the item.

---

If you still get error try this and tell me what's happened.

```
render() {
  const { subreddits } = this.state
  var subredditsArray = subreddits.map(subreddit => (
    <li 
      key={subreddit.toString()} 
      onClick={(e) => {
        console.log(subreddit.toString())
      }}
    >
      {subreddit}
    </li>
  ))

  return (
    <div className="redditResults">
      <h1>Top 10 subreddits for that topic</h1>
      <ul>{subredditsArray}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think this might be a good way to go, however, it runs into the issue that all the other comments are resulting in - it returns an undefined error when I put `this.getSubredditInfo` in the map function, but doesn't when I put it in the `<ul>` tag below in the final render return. Any ideas why it returns an error?

Comment: Do you have the full error log can we take a look? May be a screenshot or something else.That's shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lamda function or make component for item list which have own value for `getSubredditInfo` function

```
getSubredditInfo(value) {}

render() {

  var subredditsArray = this.state
   .subreddits.map((subreddit, i) => 
     (<li key={i} 
          onClick={() => this.getSubredditInfo(subreddit)}>{subreddit}</li>));

  return (
    <div className="redditResults">
      <h1>Top 10 subreddits for that topic</h1>
      <ul>{subredditsArray}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think there is an issue with having "this.getSubredditInfo" inside of the map function. It returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSubredditInfo' of undefined". Do you perhaps know why this is the case when I put it in the map function but not in the ul tag in the return statement?

Comment: Need use lamda function `=>`. It save parent context (`this`)

Answer (score 0):

1) Key should be grabbed either by the id in your object in array. Or you can combine the 2 properties to create a unique key for react to handle re-renders in a better way.

If you have a string array, you may use a combination of string value + index to create a unique value, although using index is not encouraged.

Given a quick example for both below.

2) A better way could be to move your map function into another function and call that function in render function, which will return the required JSX. It will clean your render function.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      subredditsObjArray: [
        { id: 1, value: 'A'},
        { id: 2, value: 'B'},
        { id: 3, value: 'C'},
        { id: 4, value: 'D'}
        ],
      subredditsArray: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      selectedValue: ''
    };
  }

  getSubredditInfo = (subreddit) => {
    console.log(subreddit)
    this.setState({
      selectedValue: ((subreddit && subreddit.id) ? subreddit.value : subreddit),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="redditResults">
        <p>Selected Value: {this.state.selectedValue}</p>
        <h1>Top {this.state.subredditsArray.length || '0'} subreddits for that topic</h1>
        <p>With Objects Array</p>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.subredditsObjArray
              && this.state.subredditsObjArray.map(redditObj => {
                return (<li key={redditObj.id}><button onClick={() => this.getSubredditInfo(redditObj)}>{redditObj.value || 'Not Found'}</button></li>);
              })
          }
        </ul>
        <br />
        <p>With Strings Array</p>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.subredditsArray
              && this.state.subredditsArray.map((reddit, index) => {
                return (<li key={reddit + '-' + index}><button onClick={() => this.getSubredditInfo(reddit)}>{reddit || 'Not Found'}</button></li>);
              })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App etext="Edit" stext="Save" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```